# Check if onbackeypress checked android

Tags: android

Is it possible to check if on back keypressed is checked in android within the onbackeypressed method ?

Comment: What do you mean by _onBackKeyPressed is Checked_.?

Comment: i want to know if the user click on the back key

Comment: Look at my answer. It will provide some explanation to your question.

Comment: you want to know if the user is pressing back in the onBackPressed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a condition in the method you override. To get the normal behaviour, you can use `super.onBackPressed()`. So let's say you have a `Boolean` called 'condition', and you only want to the button to do something if this `Boolean` is `true`, you can use this code for that.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(condition){
        super.onBackPressed(); //Normal behaviour
    } else {
        Log.d("Debug message", "Condition was not met"); //Other behaviour, if you want
    }
}
```

If your check is more complicated, you may want to consider putting it in a method that returns a `Boolean` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In `Activity` you can override `onBackPressed` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()` in your Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
Log.i("Pressed","Back Button Key Pressed");
// Print here to see back button is pressed.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onBackPressed()` event is invoked only when the Back key is pressed. There is nothing like checks that are invoked when the back key is pressed.

You just override the default `onBackKeyPressed()` function. Once the Back key is pressed, it will automatically get invoked.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // Here do what you want to do on back key pressed.
}
```

Comment: @sophia Can you specify which condition.?